# write spark dataframe schema to a separate file

Tags: apache-spark

Sorry to bother others. We need to write spark dataframe to a separate file. It should be something like this:

```
df.other_operations.
val schema = df.schema.toDDL
val putObjectRequest = PutObjectRequest
      .builder()
      .bucket(bucket)
      .key(key)
      .build()
s3.s3Client.putObject(putObjectRequest, RequestBody.fromString(schema))
```

related: [Store Schema of Read File Into csv file in spark scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61654023/store-schema-of-read-file-into-csv-file-in-spark-scala)

Questions:

1. Our df were mostly from reading files use spark native APIs. Do we need to cache df before reading the schema property? From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49492463/compute-size-of-spark-dataframe-sizeestimator-gives-unexpected-results), to read some stats we need to cache() the dataframe. We try to avoid it but allow spark to decide everything.
2. If I do something above, it will only dump schema once, not for each partition. Am I right? I actually want a way to pass this information to driver and let driver dump it only once. But Idk which way is best. Accumulator seems overkill.

Thanks.